# sqlite error when migrating data from sqlite3 to postgresql using pgloader

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, grafana, pgloader

I am in the process of migrating my sqlite3 data (Grafana In-built) into my newly created external postgres database.

I used this URL as reference - [https://medium.com/@yashraj45dighe/migrate-grafana-sqlite-db-to-postgresql-for-high-availability-c7303c3750ff](https://stackoverflow.com)

After restoring the schema from into postgres, I am using pgloader to copy data from my sqlite to postgres

I am using `pgloader main.load` to perform this.

Below is the content of my `main.load`

```
load database
  from sqlite:/home/XXXXXXX/grafana.db
  into postgresql://grafana:YYYYYY@99.199.199.199:5432/grafana_db
  with data only, reset sequences
  set work_mem to '16MB', maintenance_work_mem to '512 MB';
```

I am getting the below error where it says it is not able to open my grafana.db file

Note: I took the grafana.db file from the server running the grafana instance `/var/lib/grafana` directory

```
# pgloader main.load
2024-03-28T06:04:42.010000Z LOG pgloader version "3.6.7~devel"
2024-03-28T06:04:42.101001Z LOG Migrating from #<SQLITE-CONNECTION sqlite:///home/XXXXXXXXXXX/sqlite:/home/XXXXXXXXXXX/grafana.db {100673D7C3}>
2024-03-28T06:04:42.101001Z LOG Migrating into #<PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://grafana@99.199.199.199:5432/grafana_db {100673D9A3}>
2024-03-28T06:04:42.115001Z ERROR sqlite: Failed to open sqlite file #P"/home/XXXXXXXXXXX/sqlite:/home/XXXXXXXXXX/grafana.db": Could not open sqlite3 database /home/XXXXXXXXXXX/sqlite:/home/XXXXXXXXXXX/grafana.db
Code CANTOPEN: no message.
2024-03-28T06:04:42.115001Z LOG report summary reset
       table name     errors       rows      bytes      total time
-----------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  --------------
            fetch          0          0                     0.000s
  fetch meta data          0          0                     0.000s
-----------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  --------------
-----------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  --------------
```

What am I missing?

I looked at the permissions of the Grafana.db file and set it to 777. The path is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is the absolute path that was the problem.. It did not need an absolute path. I removed the absolute path and just mentioned the filename since I was running it from the directory where the grafana.db was present.